# Convert a vertical line text file to a csv file with parameters

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I tried several ways to transform the text with a column into a summarized csv file based on the contents of the file but I couldn't.

record does not start with comma = first column
record that has a comma at the beginning = concatenates with the first

When you find the next record that doesn't have a comma at the beginning, start on another line

---

Text file to process:

```
08-ipa_group
,evouth.zip
,zipe.zip
,auth-service.zip
18-ws-api_group
,mocks.zip
,auth-service.zip
,a-service.zip
```

Output

```
08-ipa_group,evouth.zip,zipe.zip,auth-service.zip
18-ws-api_group,mocks.zip,auth-service.zip,a-service.zip
```

Comment: Please add to your question which version of `sed` you are using.

Comment: Do you need to use shell? How much shell do you know? Can you use Python? it'll be easier to program something that's more correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -v ORS= '
/^[^,]/ {
  eol()
}
END {
  eol()
}
function eol() {
  if (NR > 1)
    print "\n"
}
1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty straightforward shell script that:

- creates empty string vars line and row
- reads the input file line by line, into the var line
- if the line starts with a comma (`... | grep '^,'`) it gets appended to the var row
- else (it's the first-column line), so do something with row

  - if row is not empty (its initial state), echo and append that to output.csv
  - else set to the first-col data
- finally, append row

```bash
rm -rf output.csv

line=''
row=''

while read -r line; do
    [ "$line" = '' ] && continue          # skip blank lines

    if echo "$line" | grep -q '^,'; then  # a "comma" line
        row="${row}${line}"
    else                                  # a "first-col" line
        if [ "$row" != '' ]; then         # row is not in initial state
            echo "$row" >> output.csv
        fi
        row="$line"
    fi
done < input.txt

echo "$row" >> output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

The script, `script.ed`

```
/^[^,]/t.
v/^[^,]/;/^[^,]/-j
$d
g/^[^,]/;/^,/j
,p
Q
```

---

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```